# Replace all in a specific folder

Tags: alm

In my Test Plan I have two folders. One with all my active test cases and one with all my archived test cases. I need to replace a lot of 'Affected Module' from one value to another, however - I don't want the folder with archived to be affected by this.

So, is there a way of doing search and replace only on a specific folder (and all the sub-folders) in HP ALM?

As far as I know the search and replace function in grid view replaces all instances of the value so I can't use that directly.

Comment: when you say replace from one value to another value, Is it the fields in the details section or the design steps or design parameter?

Comment: Short: field update in Details section.

Long: Test Plan -> Test cases in multiple folders -> Details -> Affected Module This list contains a range of "values" (strings) that identifies the affected module for the test case. I want to change this value from one to another. The value i want it to change to exists in the list.
Example: In affected module two values are checked, e.g. "Limited" and "Standard". I want it to be -> "Responsive" and "Standard".

So a way of changing all "Limited" to "Responsive" in the list of "Affected Module"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple OTA code that updates the field `ts_user_04` for all the test case in folder `Subject\Automated` and its sub-folder from whatever value to `Quoting`.

Please, change the column name as per your requirement. You can easily find the DB column for any field in HP ALM by going to the Management tab if you have access to it. Even otherwise you can get all the mapping by using OTA. (I hope you have the necessary access)

*Inorder to run the OTA code, you need to install **ALM Connectivity** add-in which you can get it from the tools section in your ALM home page*

```
Public TDconnection
Public reqPath
Public testPath

'Call the main Function
updateAllTests



Public Function login()
    Dim almURL, almUserName, almPassword, domain, project
    almURL = "https://.saas.hp.com/qcbin/"

    almUserName = ""
    almPassword = ""
    domain = ""
    project = ""    
    testPath = "Subject\Automated" ' Change it as per your folder structure

    Set TDconnection = CreateObject("tdapiole80.tdconnection")
    TDconnection.ReleaseConnection
    TDconnection.InitConnectionEx almURL
    TDconnection.login almUserName, almPassword
    TDconnection.Connect domain, project

End Function


Public Function updateAllTests()
    login   
    Set TreeMgr = TDconnection.TreeManager
    Set TestTree = TreeMgr.NodeByPath(testPath)
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        Set comm = TDconnection.Command
        comm.CommandText = "update test set ts_user_04='Quoting' where ts_test_id in (select ts_test_id from test, all_lists where ts_subject in (select al_item_id from all_lists where al_absolute_path like (select al_absolute_path from all_lists where al_item_id=" & TestTree.NodeID & ") || '%' ) and ts_subject = al_item_id)"
        comm.Execute
    End If
    logout
    MsgBox "Flag Update successful", vbInformation
End Function

Public Function logout()
    TDconnection.Disconnect
    TDconnection.logout
    TDconnection.ReleaseConnection
    Set TDconnection = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Barney. I don't have the necessary access to run the code, but it seems to be what I was searching for. I'll accept your answer as correct. Side note: Is this really not a functionality in ALM??